# Replacing entire tag with shortcode - JavaScript

Tags: php, shortcode, javascript

I'm trying to replace a whole tag with a shortcode, if the tag text equals a value. I'm placing this script into the footer of the page. Here's what I'm trying:

```
var stockcounter = document.getElementsByClassName("stock in-stock");

if(stockcounter[0].innerHTML=='0 in stock') {
    //Displays timer
    stockcounter[0].outerHTML = do_shortcode('[fergcorp_cdt_single date="Feb 25 2019 18:45:00"]');
}
```

This doesn't change the target tag at all. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like javascript. `do_shortcode` is a php function. I'm not sure the full context, but at the very least, you need to wrap your php function in php tags like this and add an echo:

```
<?php // Start of php file ?>
<script>
    var stockcounter = document.getElementsByClassName("stock in-stock");

    if(stockcounter[0].innerHTML=='0 in stock') {
        //Displays timer
        stockcounter[0].outerHTML = "<?php echo do_shortcode('[fergcorp_cdt_single date="Feb 25 2019 18:45:00"]'); ?>";
    }
</script>
```

I'm assuming this script is within a php file.